# Send TAB key Event using PostMessage, mfc

Tags: c++, mfc, paste

I have code which PostMessage() which pastes the Text from Clipboard text to Notepad. Now in another application their are two Edit box, in this case i want to Paste the text then Enter TAB Key Press event (i.e Using PostMessage() send TAB key event)will take , so that me to next edit control and then again I will sent the PostMessage() to paste the text from clipboard.I am able to do it for One text box. how can i do it with two or say three edit box. Here is what i have tried.

```
//CWnd *pWnd=FindWindow(NULL,_T("Untitled - Notepad"));
    CWnd *pWnd=FindWindow(NULL,_T("Visual SourceSafe Login"));
    HWND mainHwnd = pWnd->GetSafeHwnd();
    CString csNameOfWin;
    pWnd->GetWindowTextA(csNameOfWin);

    CWnd *EditHwnd = FindWindowEx(mainHwnd,NULL,"edit",NULL);
    EditHwnd->PostMessageA(WM_PASTE,0,0);
    EditHwnd->PostMessageA(VK_TAB,0,0);
    EditHwnd->PostMessageA(WM_PASTE,0,0);
```

But this doesn't work for me can someone please tell me what is the problem with the code.
Please guide me through the right path. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why don't you just find another window and paste the way you have found the first window?

Comment: I have two Edit control in same application. So how can i find the other Edit control

Comment: `VK_TAB` is not a message, it is a virtual key code. You are probably looking for `WM_KEYDOWN`.

Comment: @Jonathan Potter, Ok Sir can you please tell me how can i simulate the TAB key press using the PostMessage(), and then paste the clipboard data into next edit control.

Comment: Why Dont you try [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `WM_KEYDOWN`/`VK_TAB`. You are looking for [`WM_NEXTDLGCTL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645432.aspx).